# What’s the difference between “here we are “ & “ here we go “

Tags: word-usage, phrase-meaning

I need to know the difference between “here we go “and “ here we are “ ?

Comment: by themselves or as part of bigger sentence?

Answer (score 1):

Okay... Well, here we go. "Here we go" refers to going (active) somewhere. That somewhere may be a physical place, e.g., if two people are, hesitantly, about to jump into a cold lake, one might say to the other, "Well. He we go." And then they'd jump in together. That somewhere may be a mental place, e.g., if one person is about to explain something to another person, the explainer might begin by saying, "Well, here we go."

"Here we are" refers to being (passive) somewhere. That somewhere may be a physical place, e.g., if two people are looking at a map, one person might point to a place on the map and say, "Here we are." It probably is more commonly used when arriving somewhere, e.g., if one person is driving another person to a location, especially a location with which the passenger is unfamiliar, the driver, upon arriving, might say to the passenger, "Here we are," meaning that they have arrived at the passenger's destination. Similarly, it may be used metaphorically in a mental context, e.g., if two people are discussing something, one person might say, "Here we are" before stating the facts upon which the two people have agreed. That is, "Here we are," in that context, refers to agreeing about something.

Each of these is sometimes used when presenting someone with something. For example, when someone serves food, the person might say either "Here we go" or "Here we are" meaning the the food has arrived. Or, if you ask to borrow someone's pen, the person might say either "Here we go" or "Here we are" when handing you the pen. Although, that's more commonly "Here you go" or "Here you are."

Answer (score 0):

Let's say my friend and I are talking to you, and i get a phone call telling me to reach somewhere.
I then say to you "see you. Here we go" i.e, i am leaving you and going somewhere.

ok so now you call me, and i come to you. Now I will say "Hi, Here we are".

I hope it helps